# How to get the name of a selected textbox when click on it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save the name of a selected textbox as a string variable.
This needs to occur when the textbox is selected.

There are 100 or so textboxes within a frame. I have tried using the `frame_enter()` function to trigger the code and then use `me.frame.activecontrol.name` to set the variable value but the textbox activecontrol has not yet be set using this method and therefore won't work.

It does work if I use a button to trigger the code after the textbox has been selected but I would like it to run as soon as I have clicked the textbox.
I could use `textbox_enter()` but this will require multiple lines of code for each textbox so I am looking for a neater solution.

Comment: Private Sub frame_enter()

Dim identity As String

identity = Me.frame.ActiveControl.Name

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Class Module`. For example, you want to capture all the click as you say it on every `Textbox` in your `Userform` and get the corresponding name of it, you can try:

1. Creating a `Class Module` named `clsTextbox`

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public WithEvents tb As MSForms.TextBox

   Private Sub tb_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                            ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
     '// change this code to what you want done in Textbox name //
     MsgBox tb.Name & " was selected." 
   End Sub
   ```
2. In your `Userform` initialize all your `TextBox` and pass it to your class.

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private allTextbox() As clsTextbox

   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

     Dim fC As MSForms.Control, tbCnt As Long

     With Me
       For Each fC In .Controls
         If TypeOf fC Is MSForms.TextBox Then
           tbCnt = tbCnt + 1
           ReDim Preserve allTextbox(1 To tbCnt)
           Set allTextbox(tbCnt) = New clsTextbox
           Set allTextbox(tbCnt).tb = fC
         End If
       Next
     End With

   End Sub
   ```

Now, every time you click on any `Textbox` in your form, you will get the `MsgBox` prompt.
 I played with it a bit and can't seem to make `Enter()` event work. It is somewhat excluded to the list of events that can be handled using class (see below).

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly. I wouldn't have been able to do that without your help!