# VBA - How to pass the value from a listbox in UserformA to the textbox in UserformB by not hardcoding?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to the VBA. I am trying to make a userform to enter the information about the worker's daily duties. I tried to make a combobox to select multiple workers who have done the jobs. After google, I learnt that combobox do not have multiple selection. I changed to use listbox.

My idea is to click the textbox in Userform1, then Userform2 show. In Userform2, there is a listbox that contain all the workers in my company. Selected the workers and clicked the "OK" button, the selected workers will move back to Userform1's textbox which triggered the Userform2 appeared.

This is the code in my Userform 2:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Enter()

With lstWorker
    For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(x) Then
            If myVar = "" Then
                myVar = .List(x)
            Else
                myVar = myVar & ", " & .List(x)
            End If
        End If
    Next x
End With

UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = myVar
Me.Hide

End Sub
```

Here is my question: If it is only one textbox in Userform1, that could be already fine. But it is lots of textbox in Userform1. How to refer the "myVar" to the textbox that triggered the Userform2, instead of hardcoding the "Userform1.Textbox1.value"?

~~~

For more information, the way of the textbox trigger the Userform2, the event is the "enter". I thought "Private sub textbox1_Click" could be work, but doesn't. Is "Private sub textbox1__Enter" the correct trigger event to activate the Userform2?

Thank you!

Comment: You should never expose the controls on a form to code outside the form. This article gives hints on how to do this properly ... https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/548052/Transferring-information-between-two-forms-Part-1

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier filling a listbox which is shown in your first userform? Regardless, you might be able to use a global variable and send the name of your control object to the sub handling the filling of your listbox, the "ok" then fills the myVar into the value of the control whose name is still in the global variable.

Comment: @CHill60 I was a little bit confused of your advice. Then I checked the link you provide. I figure out it is a C# language article. (Or it is a common sense of this two language?) I am so sorry to mislead you. My situation is using VBA. I changed the title and add a [VBA] to it, trying not to mislead other people.

Comment: @Notus_Panda The reason to me for not putting a listbox in Userform 1, it could make the Userform 1 seems not tidy enough. And the main question to me is, I cannot figure out how to transfer the data from the listbox to the textbox(let's say textbox 1 to 10). If I choose the workers on the listbox, how to link the address to the textbox I just focus? In the excel, it have somethings like `"selection.offset( x, y).value = myVar"` or `"target.value = myVar"`. Is it anything like those for the userform's control object, to express  "the latest active textbox"?

Comment: To [use a control by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531249/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-a-text-box-control-instead-of-the-text-boxs-value-i) and if you do not want to type the name to pass to your other userform (or set it in a global variable), you can check [this answer with a class module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480938/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-selected-textbox-when-click-on-it)

Comment: @Light - the article uses C# as the example language but the advice is the same regardless of which language used.

Comment: @Notus_Panda I followed the method of creating a class module. It works! Only one thing: it make a looping to change all the textbox into the new class module(ie. `clstextbox`). But I want to make a exception with it, the textbox1 is reserved for typing the date of the work. How to keep the textbox1 remain to the `textbox`, other textbox (textbox2, textbox3, textbox4, etc) transfer to `clstextbox`? I had tried to add something like `If fC.Name <> "TextBox1" Then` between the looping. But it doesn't work. All the textbox become the `clstextbox`, including textbox1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Notus_Panda Somehow, the problems were solved. I deleted the old `clstextbox` and created a new one with the same code. The looping is works now with the exception. I don't know why but it is works perfectly. I cannot solve this problem without your help. Since it is based on your comments, I don't know how to submit your answer as solution.

Comment: I only provided a couple of links, you did the bulk of the work here :) Maybe just write your edited code as an answer, refer to the link and select it as correct answer. That way, others can find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should not display all your workers in one text field and certainly not in one record. You have to make a many to many relationship (google it) to store your selected workers to a Job/Project. Would be best to show them in a continuous subform.

Comment: only that there is no subforms in Excel...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).